# android RecyclerView doesn't render until keyboard open

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have big problem and i am tired.
I use recyclerview to show list from Json,
but recyclerview doesn't show data until I open keyboard (or press ALT key in Genymotion).

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the code of recyclerview

Comment: post your recyclerview related code,so that we can help.